# Variable does not exist in the current context Unity Teleportation Script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, variables

I am working on a school project and need help with a certain aspect of my code. I am making a game and wanted to include a teleport move which would be tied to the player via a vector whose angle would be controlled by the direction of the mouse.

I planned to have the location of the teleport be shown by a separate GameObject to the player and so needed to inherit information from a class in a separate object to my player. This is where the errors started. Instead of inheriting the variable final_Distance which was a vector containing the co-ordinates of the end of the vector that the player would appear at after teleporting, an error message appeared saying: "The name final_Distance does not exist in the current context. After working on this for about an hour I am truly stumped as to what I should do. I tried declaring the vector at the start of the Class which didn't work and also in the Awake void. I would appreciate help with this.

Here is my Teleportation class:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Teleport : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector2 screenPosition;
    public Vector2 worldPosition;

    private CharacterController2D characterController2D;
    private Mouse_Radius MR;

    public bool canTeleport = true;

    void Awake()
    {
        characterController2D = GetComponent<CharacterController2D>();
        MR = GetComponent<Mouse_Radius>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (canTeleport == true && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {

            T_Port();
        }

        else
        {
            bool ground_check = characterController2D.m_Grounded;

            if (!ground_check && canTeleport == false)
            {
                canTeleport = false;
            }
            else
            {
                canTeleport = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public void T_Port()
    {
        worldPosition = MR.Update(final_Distance);

        transform.position = worldPosition;

        canTeleport = false;
    }
}
```

And here is the class responsible for providing the location of the gameobject which shows where the player will end up after they teleport:

```
public class Mouse_Radius : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Player;
    public float radius;

    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void Update()
    {
        Vector2 Mouse_Cord = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y));
        Vector2 Player_Coord = Player.transform.position;

        Vector2 Player_Cursor_Distance = Mouse_Cord - Player_Coord;
        Vector2 dir = Player_Cursor_Distance.normalized;
        Vector2 cursorVector = dir * radius;

        Vector2 final_Distance = Player_Coord + cursorVector;

        transform.position = final_Distance;
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        UnityEditor.Handles.DrawWireDisc(transform.parent.position, Vector3.back, radius);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to just combine the two classes into one and instead of calling the ground check boolean from my Character Controller from inside the Teleportation void, I called it inside my FixedUpdate() void. This provided the program with enough time to pass on the boolean to the Teleportation class so that it can be used in the code. Here is the finalised code:

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Teleport : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Player;
    public float radius;
    public bool canTeleport = true;
    public Vector2 screenPosition;
    public Vector2 worldPosition;
    public bool ground_check;

    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.visible = false;
        distToGround = collider.bounds.extents.y;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector2 Mouse_Cord = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y));
        Vector2 Player_Coord = Player.transform.position;

        Vector2 Player_Cursor_Distance = Mouse_Cord - Player_Coord;
        Vector2 dir = Player_Cursor_Distance.normalized;
        Vector2 cursorVector = dir * radius;

        Vector2 final_Distance = Player_Coord + cursorVector;

        transform.position = final_Distance;

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && canTeleport == true)
        {
            T_Port(final_Distance);
        }

        else
        {
            ground_check = Player.GetComponent<CharacterController2D>().m_Grounded;

            if (!ground_check && canTeleport == false)
            {
                canTeleport = false;
            }
            else
            {
                canTeleport = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        UnityEditor.Handles.DrawWireDisc(transform.parent.position, Vector3.back, radius);
    }

    public void T_Port(Vector2 distance2)
    {
        worldPosition = distance2;

        Player.transform.position = worldPosition;

        canTeleport = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the variable *doesn't* exist in that context.  There is no variable in the `T_Port` method or its class called `final_Distance`.

Note how the code in `Mouse_Radius` first *creates* a variable and then *uses* that variable:

```
Vector2 final_Distance = Player_Coord + cursorVector;

transform.position = final_Distance;
```

Compare this with the code in `Teleport` which only tries to *use* a variable, never having *created* it:

```
worldPosition = MR.Update(final_Distance);
```

Something has to exist before it can be used.  So it's not clear what you're expecting this variable to be at this time or what value it should contain.

Taking a step back... Why are you trying to send a value to the `Update` method in the first place?  It doesn't expect one:

```
public void Update()
```

So even if you do declare your variable and assign a value to it before using it, the very next error will be telling you that you're passing a value to a method which doesn't accept one.

Since the method doesn't accept a value, don't pass it one:

```
worldPosition = MR.Update();
```

This will have the added bonus of correcting the error of trying to use a variable which doesn't exist, since you're no longer trying to use it.

**Additionally**... The `Update` method also doesn't *return anything*:

```
public void Update()
```

So assigning its return value to `worldPosition` will *also* generate an error.  Remove that assignment operation:

```
MR.Update();
```

Overall, your `Update` method accepts no parameters and produces no result, so don't try to pass it parameters and don't try to use its result.

If you *do* want to pass parameters to it and/or use a result from it, then first you'll need to modify the `Update` method to do what you want it to do, *then* you can invoke it to perform that operation.

Comment: Ah yes I forgot to say in my answer (because I didn't see yours even though it was posted first) that the code in Update() already carries out the operation so no return or assignment of worldPosition is required.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question of why `final_Distance` doesn't exist in the context, it is because the `Teleport` class doesn't have access to that variable - it is not defined in the class definition, or in the definition of any of the classes `Teleport` inherits from, and it isn't defined in the scope of the `T_Port()` method.

Luckily, in this case, it doesn't need to be. The `Update()` method of `Mouse_Radius` takes no parameters and, looking at it, does all the calculations to obtain `final_Distance` (which is defined only in the scope of the method, and so only exists in that method). Calling `Update()` on `MR` in `T_Port()` of Teleport with no parameters would work, although it should be noted that `Update()` in a MonoBehaviour is called by unity every frame. As the check for if teleportation is allowed is not in the `Update()` method of `Mouse_Radius`, unity will cause the player to teleport every frame, whether it is supposed to or not.

To sum that up, rename `Update()` in `Mouse_Radius` to something like `TeleportPlayer()` in both its definition and its use in the `Teleport` script, and also don't give it any parameters when it is called as it doesn't need any (like this - `MR.TeleportPlayer();`).